# Converting a QList to a QStringList to insert into a QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

I need to insert items into a ComboBox, but to do so, i need to have a QStringList instead of a QList.

In my .h i have the QList of a Object.

```
QList<placavideo> listaPlacavideo;
```

In my .cpp i have the implementation:

```
placavideo placavideo1;
placavideo1.setNome("EVGA NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080");
listaPlacavideo.insert(0,placavideo1);
```

I have tried this conversion based on another questions, that isn't working:

```
void intcomputer::on_box_placavideo_activated(const QString &arg1)
{
    QStringList  listaPlacavideos;
    foreach(placavideo *item, listaPlacavideo) 
        listaPlacavideos << item;

ui->box_fonte->addItems(listaPlacavideos);
}
```

The question is, how do I insert the items from listaPlacavideo into a QStringList, so I can insert the entire QStringList into the ComboBox?

Comment: Maybe `foreach (const placavideo &item, listaPlacavideo) ui->box_fonte->addItem(item.name());`? Actually, you must not convert something to `QStringList`, but insert each string directly to the combo.

Comment: @vahancho but how could I separate the items in the QList that i have inserted into strings, so i can insert each one into the combo?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make the object into a name. It is expecting a `QString` for a display name. If you want to store the objects in the combo box as well, then do something like this:

```
foreach ( plavavideo &item, listaPlacavideo ) {
    ui->box_fonte->addItem( item.getName(), item );
}
```

This will require `placavideo` to be a meta type usable by `QVariant` though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function in `placavideo` to get the name, for example `getNome()`, then you just need to change one line of code.

```
void intcomputer::on_box_placavideo_activated(const QString &arg1)
{
  QStringList  listaPlacavideos;

  foreach(const placavideo& item, listaPlacavideo)
  {
    listaPlacavideos << item.getNome();  // Add the name to the list, not the whole object
  }

  ui->box_fonte->addItems(listaPlacavideos);
}
```

EDIT: I added `const` before `placavideo&`. That should fix your error.

EDIT2: You should declare the function `getNome()` as const.

```
QString getNome() const;
```

Comment: When i compile i get this:     note:   in expansion of macro 'Q_FOREACH'
 #define foreach Q_FOREACH
                     ^
note: in expansion of macro 'foreach'
   foreach(placamae &item, listaPlacamae) // para cada item na lista, adiciona o getNome de cada item e joga para dentro da QStringList
   ^
..\MontaComputer\intcomputer.cpp: In member function 'void intcomputer::on_box_placavideo_activated()':
error: binding 'const placavideo' to reference of type 'placavideo&' discards qualifiers

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm still getting error:                                                                           error: passing 'const placavideo' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     listaPlacavideos << item.getNome();
                                      ^

Comment: @Pedrink, you need to declare the function `getNome()` as const.